# Toggle ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I have a string in my scope and I don't always know whether I want the HTML escaped. Essentially I have a boolean which will say whether or not the HTML should be escaped.

#### Code

Here's some of my example code:

```
$scope.result = "<b>foo</b>bar";
$scope.html = false; // In this case the HTML *would* be escaped
```

Here's a case where the HTML would be inserted like `innerHTML`:

```
$scope.result = "<strike>foo</strike>bar";
$scope.html = true; // The HTML would be escaped
```

#### Other Solutions I've Tried

I'm not sure what would be the *"Angular Way"* to do this, and while I have thought of hacks using `.removeAttribute`, I find this *very* hacky and there *must* be a better way.

Comment: Why not using a directive where you pass an attributes that indicatei if teh HTML be escaped? Something like this <example-bind ng-show="html"/>

Answer (score 1):

> An example went something like:

```
<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="data.markupData"></p>
```

> Iteration with ng-repeat was also straightforward:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.markupData"></p>
</div>
```

#### 1. Create a new controller

```
var ExampleCtrl = function($scope) {
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="example in Examples" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="trustedExample"></p>

<hr />

</div>
```

#### 2. Add the Strict Contextual Escaping service to your controller

```
var ExampleCtrl = function($scope, $sce) {

}
```

#### 3. Use $sce.trustAsHtml function on data

```
var ExampleCtrl = function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trustedExample = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.example);
}
```

**I Hope This Will help**

Comment: So based on a boolean scope variable, how would I toggle between `bind-html-unsafe` and `bind-html`?

Answer (score 0):

One 'angular' way of doing this would be to write a `filter` that takes in the html and the boolean value and returns escaped/unescaped html.

Here's a basic tutorial on how to write an dngular filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

On how to excape html, try using `$sanitize`: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize